# I cannot understand Finite Difference Method exactly

Tags: graphics, directx, numerical-analysis

I am a student who studies DirectX 11. To calculate the normal vector of the surface, I know I need to get two tangent vectors to calculate the cross product. But I can do it if there is the equation of surface.

If I don't know the equation/formula of surface, I have to get the approximation of normal vector using Finite Difference Method. Below code is from the book I am reading.

```
for(UINT i = 1; i < mNumRows-1; ++i)
{
    for(UINT j = 1; j < mNumCols-1; ++j)
    {
        float l = mCurrSolution[i*mNumCols+j-1].y;
        float r = mCurrSolution[i*mNumCols+j+1].y;
        float t = mCurrSolution[(i-1)*mNumCols+j].y;
        float b = mCurrSolution[(i+1)*mNumCols+j].y;
        mNormals[i*mNumCols+j].x = -r+l;
        mNormals[i*mNumCols+j].y = 2.0f*mSpatialStep;
        mNormals[i*mNumCols+j].z = b-t;

        XMVECTOR n = XMVector3Normalize(XMLoadFloat3(&mNormals[i*mNumCols+j]));
        XMStoreFloat3(&mNormals[i*mNumCols+j], n);
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why the values `-r+l` and `b-t` (the difference of y value) become the normal vector's x value and z value, respectively. I wonder why `2.0f * mSpatialStep` is the y value, too.

Answer (score 0):

A derivative is numerically estimated by `Ft ~ (F(t+step) - F(t-step))/ (2 step)`. Observe how the given normal vector is proportional to the estimate of the gradient of `y = - F(x, z)`, i.e. `(Fx, 1, Fz)`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering my question. I understood the code tries to get the approximation of gradient vector. I wonder that why normal vector's x and z value must be the difference of y value of the difference of neighbor vertices. Is it partial difference value like ∂y / ∂x and ∂y / ∂z ?

Comment: And I wonder why the code uses - F(x, z) not F(x, z).

Comment: @zhoyic: that is precisely what my answer says.

Comment: @zhoyic: yes, the code uses F(x, z), not not F(x, z).

Comment: Ah.. I wondered why the minus is added in front of F(x,z). why not just +F(x,z)